# Can an object of class type T be constant initialized when T has a non-trivial destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Let's look at this sample of code:

```
class D
{
    public:
    constexpr D(int val) : i(val) { };
    ~D() { };

    private:
    int i;
};

D d(3);
```

According to the documentation, D should be [constant initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization):

> Only the following variables are constant initialized: [...]
>   2. Static or thread-local object of class type that is initialized by a
>   constructor call, if the constructor is constexpr and all constructor
>   arguments (including implicit conversions) are constant expressions,
>   and if the initializers in the constructor's initializer list and the
>   brace-or-equal initializers of the class members only contain constant
>   expressions.

Indeed, `d` is initialized by constructor call, the constructor of `D` is `constexpr` and my argument (`3`) is a constant expression.

However, to specify to the compiler the value of a variable can be evaluated at compile time, it is possible to use [`constexpr` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr). But, in this case, it won't compile because `D` is not a [*LiteralType*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType) because it define a non-trivial constructor.

So, in my snippet, is `d` really constant initialized? If so, why can't I use `constexpr` specifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, in my snippet, is `d` really constant initialized? If so, why can't I use `constexpr` specifier?

Yes, it will be constant initialized. As you've quoted, constant initialization doesn't need the type to be a LiteralType. But `constexpr` does need it. Your type is not a LiteralType, so it cannot be a `constexpr`. But the type and constructor call fulfills the requirements of being constant initialization.

Btw., C++20 will have [constinit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constinit). With this, you can make sure that a variable gets static initialized (which means constant initialization in your case).

You can check out constinit for your example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/_L8y5N), as a further evidence that it compiles successfully, and you can see that the object is initialized at compile-time (not a requirement by the standard, but GCC does it).